# Is it likely that a sentient AI experience synesthesia?

Tags: computer-vision, audio-processing, sentience

The reason I ask this question is because we humans tend to compartmentalize our sensory inputs, except in some individuals that experience synesthesia.  If an Artificial Intelligence Entity (AIE) can correlate all sensory input (as a bunch of tensors), wouldn't that be the ultimate form of synesthesia?

An AIE geometry / color synesthesia might lead to an explanation of how Joan Miro colorized his doodles.